# SQL to QueryBuilder

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

first, sorry for bad English!

I try to convert this SQL (it's operational):

```
SELECT DISTINCT U.id
FROM User U
INNER JOIN Detail DE on U.id = DE.id_user
INNER JOIN matiere MA on U.id = MA.id_user
WHERE DE.ville = $var1
AND MA.matiere = $var2
```

in query builder.
I have try this:

```
$query = $repository->createQuerybuilder('U.id')
     ->from('User', 'U')
     ->innerJoin('Detail', 'DE', 'WITH', ' U.id = DE.id_user' )
     ->innerJoin('matiere', 'MA', 'WITH', 'U.id = MA.id_user')
     ->where('DE.ville = :ville')
     ->setParameter('ville', $ville)
     ->andWhere('MA.matiere = :matiere')
     ->setParameter('matiere', $matiere)
     ->distinct();
```

but I have this error: 
"[Syntax Error] line 0, col 49: Error: Expected end of string, got '.' "

And when I try this:

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('U.id')
    ->from('User', 'U')
    ->innerJoin('Detail', 'DE', 'WITH', ' U.id = DE.id_user' )
    ->innerJoin('matiere', 'MA', 'WITH', 'U.id = MA.id_user')
    ->where('DE.ville = :ville')
    ->setParameter('ville', $ville)
    ->andWhere('MA.matiere = :matiere')
    ->setParameter('matiere', $matiere)
    ->distinct();
```

I have this error:

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::createQueryBuilder(),
```

I work with doctrine and symfony3.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

This is like a syntax error , both the function of development in the query builder as the own instance of the query , try to make a debug and see how the SQL query is being built , syntax error possibly.

```
$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $qb->getQuery();
$debug = $query->debug();
```

has a space between the strings [ ' U.id = DE.id_user ' ) ] , remove these spaces to try to surround the possible error;

**or you can try make this way, probably work:**

```
  $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder(); <!--separte constructor this line-->

  $query->select('U.id')
    ->from('User', 'U')
    ->innerJoin('Detail', 'DE', 'WITH', 'U.id = DE.id_user' ) <!--align this line-->
    ->innerJoin('matiere', 'MA', 'WITH', 'U.id = MA.id_user')
    ->where('DE.ville', ':ville') <!--separate this line-->
    ->setParameter('ville', $ville)
    ->andWhere('MA.matiere', ':matiere') <!--separate this line-->
    ->setParameter('matiere', $matiere)
    ->distinct()
    ->getQuery(); <!--add this line-->

    $resp = $query->getResult(); <!--get the answer this line-->
```

Comment: I have try your solution, the error is the same (Warning: Missing argument 1 for Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::createQueryBuilder(),)

I have try to delete 'select(U.id') and put  'createQuerybuilder('U.id');'
and the same error (' [Syntax Error] line 0, col 49: Error: Expected end of string, got '.' ')

I don't understand where is the problem...

Comment: You did debug? It is important to know how is the SQL query in your variable ,
it seems that is prompting a syntax error when executing the
SQL query , the error [ Expected end of string , got . ' '] , it seems that the lexical analyzer
It is waiting for a character to close the string sentence and execute it properly, or has a character point [ . ]
out of order in the SQL string , disrupting running correctly and generating the error

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
$query = $repository->createQuerybuilder('U.id')
```

You are trying to pass a object and method call instead of just a single parameter. That why the error about the dot.

Use this instead before the querybuilder to get the ID:

```
$id = U.id
```

or

```
$id = $U->getId();
```

then pass in parameter:

```
$query = $repository->createQuerybuilder($id )
...
```

Then you won't get the error: "[Syntax Error] line 0, col 49: Error: Expected end of string, got '.' "